# Ubuntu is not detecting headphonejack on my asus laptop

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

So I tried to plug in my analog headphones to the laptop but it does not seem to detect it. When I check my sound settings the headphones does not show up.

When I checked the alsa-mixer it didn't show up there either.

This is what i get from doing this command

```
wget http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh -O alsa-info.sh && bash alsa-info.sh

ALSA Information Script v 0.4.64
--------------------------------

This script visits the following commands/files to collect diagnostic
information about your ALSA installation and sound related hardware.

  dmesg
  lspci
  lsmod
  aplay
  amixer
  alsactl
  /proc/asound/
  /sys/class/sound/
  ~/.asoundrc (etc.)

See 'alsa-info.sh --help' for command line options.

Automatically upload ALSA information to www.alsa-project.org? [y/N] : y
Uploading information to www.alsa-project.org ...  Done!

Your ALSA information is located at http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=a79b61db881f5e9829350e58248ea9ddd22280d0

Please inform the person helping you.
```